# Weird beavior of autocompleted words on AHK after pressing spacebar twice

Tags: autohotkey

If I press <kbd>space</kbd>twice after an autocorrected word, it deletes the last 3 letters of the autocompleted word and writes the same autocompleted word again. The code is:

```
::agm::Good morning
```

desired working behavior:

```
 agm + SPACE generates "Good morning"
```

but if I press <kbd>space</kbd> twice after the "m" or if I press <kbd>space</kbd>, then the result is:

```
 agm  + SPACE + SPACE generates "Good morniGood morning"
```

Comment: Could you show us the exact code you are running? I am unable to replicate this behavior.

Comment: I guess you are right, I've edited the question for a more explanatory, better formatted one. I hope that's good now.

Comment: @Tom A good start, but please further edit your question to include the actual AutoHotkey script that's showing the misbehavior; from what's currently available, it looks like there's something weird about how that code is handling keypresses, but without seeing the code it's not possible to investigate far enough into the problem for anyone to provide a useful answer.

Comment: I don't think I can include the script in here, it's huge. It's the famous autocorrect script that used common misspellings from the English language from a wikipedia list to correct them, I've basically added some of my own for canned phrases and whatnot. it's basically a huge script with ::something::generated phrase